# Q: Allow API to access files otherwise denied by FilesMatch

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to stop people from downloading full-size images from my WordPress blog, so I've put this .htaccess file in the uploads folder.

```
<FilesMatch "\.jpg$">
    ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg$">
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Works great, sends them to a 404 page. But I have a plugin that sends images to an API for auto-tagging and I think this file is blocking the API. How can I allow access to the API inside this file? I've tried adding the API URL to an allow, but not sure this is the right way to do it?

Comment: You need to find something that makes these API requests distinguishable from other types of request. Could be the requesting IP or host name, a specific User Agent, …

Comment: Like the API URL? E.g. https://api.appname.com

Comment: That is where your plugin sends its requests to, but that will not necessarily be the host name of the system that makes the requests for your images in the “other direction”. You’ll have to figure out which unique request characteristics exist yourself (by doing some logging on your end, when any of these images gets requested by the API), or check their documentation on whether they offer any info on that.